# Get AdministratorsMembers SIDs in .NET CORE 2

Tags: c#, com, .net-core, ienumerable, sid

I wrote this function to retrieve all Administrators Members SIDs:

```
private IList<byte[]> GetAdministratorsMembersSIDs()
{
    IList<byte[]> adminMembers = new List<byte[]>();

    SecurityIdentifier id = new SecurityIdentifier(administratorsSid);
    string name = id.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value.Split('\\')[1];

    using (DirectoryEntry adminGroupEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://./{0},group", name)))
    {                
        foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)adminGroupEntry.Invoke("Members"))
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(member))
            {
                adminMembers.Add((byte[])memberEntry.InvokeGet("objectSid"));
            }
        }
    }

    return adminMembers;
}
```

In .NET Core 2.1 `adminGroupEntry.Invoke("Members")` throw a *System.PlatformNotSupportedException: IDispatch and IDispatchEx are not supported*.
 Anyone knows a workaround compatible in .NET Core 2.1 ?

**[EDIT]**
[Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30011#issuecomment-446334885) fixed in .NET Core  3.0